# Using php, how to get return object data into variable?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have read a number of the answers on this but I am not getting something.  I have an object that retrieves data from a file and puts into an array format and I am trying to get the data into a variable in the calling file so that I can work with the data.

```
 calling.php

    $x = new obj();
    $x -> method_y();

 objectfile.php

    public function method_y(){
       ..... code does stuff .....
       print_r($array);
    }

    array(
         [0] => array
             (
                 [key1] => value1
                 [key2] => value2
                 [key3] => value3
             )
          [1] => array
             (
                 [key1] => value1
                 [key2] => value2
                 [key3] => value3
              )
    )
```

Is is better to use an echo, return, or print from the method and should I use the json_encode to return it.  How do I get the returned data into out of the object into something I can work with. For instance using the json_encode in the method I get back json but the json_decode wants a string.

Again I have read a number of answers on this but I am not getting it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can as well return the array itself, and then traverse the array using for loops, maybe something like this

```
public function method_y(){
    ..... code does stuff .....
    return $array;
}

$var = $x -> method_y();

foreach($var as $element) {
    foreach($element as $key => $value) {
          echo $key;
          echo $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed my calling file to have $j = $x -> method_y(); and when I try to loop over $j I get the error Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

Comment: `var_dump($j);` tell me the result of this

Comment: NULL. I tried return $array and print_r($array) from the method.  The print_r puts it to the screen but the $j is NULL.  Not sure if this makes a difference but I am running from command line using 5.6 on Windows 7.

Comment: The system has nothing to do with it, are you sure you are generating the array to be returned right?

Comment: Ok this is where being rusty meets Doh! I am using a call to a method_x to call method_y.  I have a return in method_y but not in method_x. Getting data on the screen was leading me in the wrong direction. Problem solved. Thanks.